# Botão stick somente aparece ao passar do botão principal adicionar ao carrinho

Tags: javascript, rolamento

Preciso fazer uma modificação de um codigo que já está pronto, estou com uma loja na shopify no tema warehouse e quero que o botão stick somente apareça no mobile quando rolar a página e sumir de vista o botão de adicionar ao carrinho. o codigo usa um pageoffset especifico mas dependendo da quantidade de variações pode aparecer mais cedo ou tarde do que deveria então queria definir para aparecer so quando passar do botão principal de adicionar ao carrinho.

[o botão deveria aparecer quando a tela descer exatamente abaixo do botão de cima](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAxe1.png)

estou usando esses codigos

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
window.onscroll = function() {
  var pageOffset = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop,
      btn = document.getElementById('scrollToTop');
  if (btn) btn.style.display = pageOffset > 1200 ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

}

```
<div id="scrollToTop" class="botaoflutuante">        
        <span class="button button--primary" id="clicar" data-action="add-to-cart">{{ 'product.form.add_to_cart' | t }}</span>
      
      <script>
        $("#clicar").on("click", function() {
          $(".product-form__add-button").trigger("click");
        });
      </script>
    </div>
```

acredito que precise colocar alguma condição no codigo java script mas não conheço praticamente nada preciso da ajuda de vocês.

Usei o código do amigo e ficou assim

```
const btnBuy = document.getElementsByClassName('botaoflutuante')[0];
const addToCard = document.getElementsByClassName('product-form__add-button button button--primary')[0];

if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
  window.onscroll = function() {
    const windowTop = window.pageYOffset;
    
if (windowTop > addToCard.offsetTop + addToCard.offsetHeight) {
    btnBuy.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    btnBuy.style.display = 'none';
}
```

porém ele está mostrando o botão stick rolando pouca coisa abaixo do botão principal, já tentei mudar as class com outros elementos mas não tive sucesso

[Imagem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRqiT.png)
[Imagem 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILFCM.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Não dá pra eu te ajudar 100%, pois você não mandou um código completo o suficiente para ter uma alteração. Eu refiz aqui do zero, você pode pegar e implementar ai no seu site. Qualquer coisa, adiciona o código ai que eu implemento pra vc.

Veja:

> Esses "(<br. />" foi para a pagina poder ter rolamento e vc ver o efeito.

```js
const btnBuy = document.getElementsByClassName('buy')[0];
const addToCard = document.getElementsByClassName('addToCart')[0];

if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
  window.onscroll = function() {
    const windowTop = window.pageYOffset;
    
    if (windowTop > addToCard.offsetTop + addToCard.offsetHeight) {
        btnBuy.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        btnBuy.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.buy {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<button class="addToCart">Adicionar no Carrinho</button>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<button class="buy">COMPRAR</button>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: Essa variável `addToCard` foi um exemplo que dei. Ela deverá ser a variável do botão de cima da sua pagina, pra o código verificar quando ele passar da janela e assim mostrar o botão de baixo.

Comment: Muito bom seu código, não sei oque estou errando ele mostra o botão quando eu rolo um pouco abaixo do botão não quando ele sai da tela.

Comment: Esse conceito de "sair da tela" é: a partir do momento que a posição Y do botão de cima + a altura do botão de cima é menor que a posição Y da tela, janela do usuário.  Você precisa verificar isso. Se puder me enviar o HTML mais completo, eu consigo fazer aqui pra ti.

Answer (score -3):

```
const btnBuy = document.getElementsByClassName('botaoflutuante')[0];
const addToCart = document.getElementsByClassName('product-form__add-button button button--primary')[0];

if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
  window.onscroll = function() {
    const windowTop = window.pageYOffset;
    
    btnBuy.style.display = (windowTop > addToCart.offsetTop + addToCart.offsetHeight ? 'block' : 'none');
  }
}
```

Tenta assim.

Comment: Testei também, mas o problema não ta no codigo ele funciona certinho no tema Dawn, estou usando o warehouse, creio que ele tem alguma coisa na página do produto que não deixa funcionar como eu gostaria.

Comment: o tema é esse https://themes.shopify.com/themes/warehouse/styles/metal/preview

Comment: Consegui resolver mudando o css do (.card e .card__section) de position: relative; para position: auto; ficou show muito obrigado sem o seu codigo não conseguiria ter feito

Comment: Entendi mano. Que bom que conseguiu. É nois mano tmj